# NodeMCU restarts with bootreason 2, 3

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I have two NodeMCU (Wemos D1 Mini) boards which are randomly rebooting after a few minutes or hours.  A call to node.bootreason() returns 2, 3 after a random reboot, indicating a software watchdog reset.  However, I never enable the software watchdog.  What might be causing these reboots?

I'm running NodeMCU master, float build, built on 2017-08-15 by the online build server.

The following init.lua exhibits the reboot problem.

```
-- connect to WLAN
dofile("wifi_config.lc")

-- create an MQTT client object
m = mqtt.Client("nodemcu03", 120)

function update()
    local boot_reason_basic, boot_reason_ext = node.bootreason()
    local s = table.concat({tmr.time(),
        boot_reason_basic,
        boot_reason_ext,
        node.heap()}, ",")
    if not m:publish("/NodeStability", s, 0, 0, nil) then
        mytimer:unregister()
        do_mqtt_connect()
    end
end

function handle_mqtt_error(client, reason)
    tmr.create():alarm(10 * 1000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, do_mqtt_connect)
end

mytimer = tmr.create()
function do_mqtt_connect()
    m:connect("mqttbroker.localdomain", 1883, 0,
        function()
            mytimer:register(500, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, update)
            mytimer:start()
        end,
        handle_mqtt_error)
end

do_mqtt_connect()
```

The content of the wifi_config.lua (before compiling to wifi_config.lc) is

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config{ssid="MY_SSID",pwd="MY_PASSWORD"}

wifi.eventmon.register(wifi.eventmon.STA_GOT_IP, function(T)
    print("\n\tSTA - GOT IP".."\n\tStation IP: "..T.IP.."\n\tSubnet mask: "..
        T.netmask.."\n\tGateway IP: "..T.gateway)
end)
```

Comment: Have you tried removing parts of your code to find the culprit?

Comment: I removed as much as possible, while keeping MQTT publishing.  I still see similar reboots with bootreason 2, 3.